# Using PEM file for jmeter auth

Tags: jmeter, pem

In the project, pem file is being used for auth while making calls to other services. pem file is basically a private key and bunch of certificates.

```
client = AuthRestClient::Client.new(:username => "user.name",
                                    :authn_key => "#/ssl/cert.pem",
                                    :authn_url => "http://10.10.10.10",
                                    :client_id => "http://10.11.11.11:80")

result = JSON.parse(client.get("http://10.11.11.11/test"))["test"]
```

I need to use the same pem file to do load testing on the servers using JMeter. Is this possible? Please help.

Answer (score -1):

You’ll first need to convert pem fil to jks.

Then you can use Keystore configuration element and set required properties :

- https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Keystore_Configuration

For full details see:

- https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-use-multiple-certificates-when-load-testing-secure-websites